# I've created the form but yet the namespace cannot be found?

Tags: c#, winforms

The bottom code to open a form works but yet the top one does not, I can't think why?

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Hide();
    PatientProfile Profile = new PatientProfile();
    PatientProfile.Show();   
}

private void returnTologin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Hide();
    Login Login = new Login();
    Login.Show();

}
```

Comment: What's your question exactly?

Comment: Which namespace can't be found? Can you expand your question with more information.

Comment: I think we need just a little more info than this

Comment: Right. The code above is button code to open a form, for some reason its like the form patient profile does not exist, this is the code i have always used to open forms.

Comment: @Joe Bell: Why must you give your variables the same name as your classes? Not that that's the source of the problem (cf type inference) but I know I'll find it confusing very quickly.

Comment: You can edit Question to add Details.

Comment: @bolt, @Joe: The naming may very well be the source of the problem. It sure makes the problem harder to see.

Comment: @Henk Holterman: You're right.

Comment: @Joe: Without reading the rest of the code, the 2 samples are not the same. Use `Profile.Show()` instead of `PatientProfile.Show()` to make them equal. And then start renaming stuff.

Comment: I dont see how this can be the problem, ive just created a form like any other, i dont see why i shouldnt be able to link too it like any other???

Comment: For the record, before the edit the variable was declared with the name `PatientProfile`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the PatientProfile form in a sub-folder of your project?

For example, in a folder called '`Patient`'?

If so, c# helpfully appends the name of your sub-folder to the Projects Namespace, which could result in the error you're having.

If this is the case there are two fixes;

- Open the PatientProfile form and remove additional ending on it's namespace (i.e. `namespace Project.Patient` -> `namespace Project`)
- Or, add the additional namespace in a `using` statement on your calling form (i.e. `using Project.Patient;`)

Comment: no not at all, patient profile is just a form in my project that ive created like any other.

Answer (score 3):

I dont know if this is your actual problem, since the description isnt very clear, but surely

`PatientProfile.Show();`

Should be:

`Profile.Show();`

You are calling .Show() on the class, not your instance of it.